# Is there a way to automatically create test cases in Python's unittest framework?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Suppose we would like to write test cases for a (simple) math library that (currently) only implements two routines `sqrt` and `ln`.  Among other things, both routines are expected to raise a `ValueError` if their input is negative.  So, the test cases would look like this:

```
import unittest
from my_math_lib import sqrt, ln

class TestSqrt(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_negatives(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, sqrt, -5)

    # ... any many other cases 

class TestLn(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_negatives(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, ln, -5)

    # ... any many other cases
```

Obviously the two test cases `TestSqrt.test_negatives` and `TestLn.test_negatives` are identical except for the function that is being tested, and repeating exactly the same code is a bad idea.

Is there away to auto-generate such test cases?  For example, in C/C++ one could have implemented a macro that defines the test code with the appropriate function name.   Is there a similar solution in Python?

Comment: You could extract a base class with the methods that apply to both. Or just tolerate some mild duplication.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Should the base class sub-class `unittest.TestCase` ? And how the base class should know which function it is supposed to test?

Comment: 1. It could, or it could be a mix-in alongside it. 2. Define a method/property that supplies the specific function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the possibility to subclass as proposed by @jonrsharpe, though that has one caveat. You cannot derive your base class from `unittest.TestCase` and write a `testXXX` there, because that also would be found and executed, and would fail. You need a mix-in instead:

```
class BaseTest:
    def setUp(self):
        self.tested = None

    def test_negatives(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.tested, -5)

class TestSqrt(unittest.TestCase, BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tested = sqrt

class TestLn(unittest.TestCase, BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tested = log
```

This works, but is not nice because the base class calls a method from `TestCase` (`assertRaises`) that it is not derived from, so every linter or IDE check will warn you about this.

To work around that problem, you could just use one of the real implementations as the base class:

```
class TestSqrt(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tested = sqrt

    def test_negatives(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.tested, -5)

class TestLn(TestSqrt):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tested = log

class TestSomethingElse(TestSqrt):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tested = something_else
```

What I would use instead is fixture parametrization, if you can use pytest:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[sqrt, log])
def tested_function(request):
    return request.param

def test_negatives(tested_function):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        tested_function(-5)

def test_something_else(tested_function):
    ...
```

You could also put that into a class, of course.
Caveat: this does not work with `unittest`, or at least I don't know a clean way to do it.